# Is it possible to pass values to a table type parameter from PYODBC to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I created a test type as a table with the below columns:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestType] AS TABLE
                                (
                                    [TestField] [varchar](10) NULL,
                                    [TestField2] [int] NULL
                                )
```

I then created a stored procedure the takes that table type as a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestTypeProcedure (@tt TestType READONLY)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM @tt;
```

My goal is to be able to pass something like a list of lists as the parameter for the table type. Is that even possible?

```
myList = [['Hello!', 1], ['Goodbye!', 2]]
....
cursor.execute('{{Call {TestTypeProcedure} ({?})}}', myList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

You are getting that error because a table-valued parameter is a list of iterables (preferably tuples) ...

```python
my_tvp = [('Hello!', 1), ('Goodbye!', 2)]
print(f"my_tvp contains {len(my_tvp)} row(s)")
# my_tvp contains 2 row(s)
```

... and if you pass that directly to `.execute()` then each row is interpreted as a parameter value:

```python
sql = "{CALL TestTypeProcedure (?)}"
params = my_tvp
print(f"calling SP with {len(params)} parameter value(s)")
# calling SP with 2 parameter value(s)
crsr.execute(sql, params)  # error
```

Therefore, you need to wrap your tvp inside a tuple to make it a single parameter value

```python
sql = "{CALL TestTypeProcedure (?)}"
params = (my_tvp, )  # tuple containing a single tvp "object"
print(f"calling SP with {len(params)} parameter value(s)")
# calling SP with 1 parameter value(s)
crsr.execute(sql, params)  # no error
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes so much sense. It's working now, so thanks for your help. Also, I've seen your name around here a lot and so many questions I've had have been answered by you already. Thanks for all the help you give to people around here.

Answer (score 0):

Table Value Parameters (TVP) is supported in Python: 3.7.4 and pyodbc: 4.0.26.

There is an open feedback that claims (I did not tested it) that you must create the type, in the SQL Server side, using the schema dbo

You can read more about it in the following GitHub feedback:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/595

Update: You can follow Microsoft "Getting Started" document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hmmm, I can't seem to get it to work. It seems to be reading each list inside the list as a parameter because I keep getting this issue: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: Follow Microsoft "Getting Started|" document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15