# Is it possible to pass in Table-Valued Parameters to PYODBC query?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I know I can pass a TVP to a stored procedure (as it's a question I've asked here before). I'm wondering now if this is something I can do in Python. I keep on getting this error. It's saying there's an invalid type, so would the parameter need to know what type I'm passing in?

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type READONLY. (2715) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@P1". (1087); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P1' has an invalid data type. (2724)')

```
from src.data.dbaccess import con

queryString2 = """ 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @t As Table(
PersonName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT *
FROM ?

SELECT * FROM @t
"""

data = ([('Jim', ), ('Bob', )],)

with pyodbc.connect(con.conString) as testCon:
    crsr = testCon.execute(queryString2, data)
    for row in crsr:
        print(row)
```

** Edit to clarify. In my question last year, I asked if a I could pass a TVP to a SQL Server stored procedure. This time, the procedure is being natively my Python code. This is the issue I'm trying to address now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass values to a table type parameter from PYODBC to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148084/is-it-possible-to-pass-values-to-a-table-type-parameter-from-pyodbc-to-sql-serve)

Comment: No, and that's actually my own question from last year. The difference this time is that I have the entirety of the code in Python, compared to a SQL server stored procedure last time.

Comment: Whoops that's funny :-) But looking at your current code: you should just pass through the TVP as a paramter with the name `@t` then you can select straight out of it. I don't understand why you want that `insert` there at all. Or does pyodbc force the name to be `@p1` then just use that?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that what you describe is not possible. The thing about an anonymous code block is that it doesn't have a mechanism for declaring input and output parameters like a stored procedure does, and SQL Server requires that TVPs be declared as READONLY parameters. SQL Server does offer a way to declare temporary stored procedures (similar to temporary tables) but I just tried a quick test and temporary stored procedures apparently cannot accept user-defined types as parameters.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. I usually prefer to let SQL Server do the data processing. I mainly have my queries in stored procedures, but this was something that I wasn't going to need to do again, so I wondered if I could do without the procedure. Maybe I'll go with processing the data in Python and use an executemany. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @GordThompson That is not true at all. I use ad-hoc batches with TVPs very often in C#, just declare them as `ParameterDirection.Input`. I'm unsure how you do it with pyodbc though

Comment: @Charlieface I think he was referring of a way to do it with PYODBC.

Comment: As I said, have you tried `select * from @p1` by itself, no extra code?

Comment: Looking a little at the docs: perhaps you can do something with `cursor.setinputsizes`? I must say: [this github issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/595) doesn't look very promising

Comment: @Charlieface - For C# if you are referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-parameterized-sql-statement) then pyodbc doesn't have a parameter object to control things like `ParameterDirection`. In fact, Python's DBAPI spec doesn't talk much about stored procedures except for the optional [callproc()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#callproc) method which pyodbc does not implement because it is not a good fit with the way the TDS protocol works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the question, it is possible to pass a TVP to an anonymous code block from C# using `System.Data.SqlClient` like so:

```cs
var tvpData = new DataTable();
tvpData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
tvpData.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 });
tvpData.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });

using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=127.0.0.1,49242;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @p1", con))
    {
        SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tvpData);
        tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.dboListInt";  // an existing user-defined table type

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Console.WriteLine("rows returned:");
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

console output:

```
rows returned:
1
2
```

However, that won't work with an ODBC connection from C# using `System.Data.Odbc` because the code relies on the `SqlClient`-specific `SqlDbType.Structured` type.

pyodbc does not have a similar mechanism for specifying a "structured" (TVP) parameter type. Instead, it deduces the presence of a table-valued parameter by the "shape" of the parameters it receives (e.g., a row represented by a tuple of elements, one of which is itself a list of tuples).

Furthermore, the conversation between pyodbc and the ODBC driver currently does not fully account for user-defined types as parameters for anything other than a normal stored procedure call. (It would be nice if we could use a temporary stored procedure — `CREATE PROCEDURE #myTempSP …` — but testing indicates that temporary stored procedures cannot work with user-defined table types.)

TL;DR — TVPs can be passed to an anonymous code block from C# but (currently) not from Python via pyodbc.

Comment: Thanks Gord. It seems like the main two options we have for PYODBC are to use a stored procedure or read in data to Python, process it, and then insert it back into the DB (if inserting multiple rows using fast_executemany).

Comment: If we already have Python data in "tabular form" (a list of "rows" where each "row" is a tuple of "columns") which we would otherwise pass directly as a TVP we could always push them up to the server as a #temp table. Then an anonymous code block (using the same connection) could pull the values into a user-defined table variable as illustrated [here](https://pastebin.com/bUCymDVe).